# Xamarin optimization for google play

Tags: xamarin, optimization, proguard

My xamarin application throws an error at google play. It says it is not optimized and does not allow me to publish it. I read about proguard but i have not installed it and don't know how to do it. How can i install proguard in visual sudio 2019 community. Is there a another way to optimize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin currently supports that technology only in preview. You can use Proguard or R8, but it has nothing to do with the message that you see.

You can publish the app, this is just a warning.

Comment: The button start rollout to production is not enabled. It does not allow me to publish it. It is indeed a warning but it does not allow me to proceed. How can i use Proguard?

Comment: You haven't probably published to alpha/beta so you can't roll out.

Comment: You were right of coure. I hadn't uploaded 2 photos. That was the problem. Sorry but i am new to mobile applications.